# How to access SkiaSharp color palette for quantization purposes?

Tags: c#, image-processing, quantization, skiasharp, skia

I'm trying to make a quantizer that works with SkiaSharp right now. For that purpose I need a way to get a ColorPalette or a way to work with indexed color format in SkiaSharp. I see that Index8 is no longer a supported ColorType, and a lot of the methods surrounding it appear to be deprecated. Is there a new way to modify and use an image color palette with SkiaSharp? Thanks.

I am unable to use System.Drawing.Common because it will not be supported on all platforms.